# Custom Cocoa touch control and initialization

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, custom-controls

I have designed a nice custom control CustomUIView as a subclass of UIview, with a nice initialiser that takes in 8 parameters. I made it to be the designated initializer to make sure, any user will provide all the 8 parameters correctly.
After few days, I wanted to reuse that control in a different project where nibs are used.
I added a basic UIView into the canvas of one of the NIBs and changed The Custom class option to my CustomUIView class. But I immediately realised my nice initializer is of no use, since it is not called at all.

What would you recommend to do about this? I want to ensure that

1. all the parameters are taken in but at the same time
2. I want basic positioning of that custom control in IB.

Comment: 8 Parameters!?  Are you sure there isn't any way you could flatten that down and make them all properties?

Comment: I swear, no. All 8 are essential. Without answering any of them, it's impossible to construct that control.
I can't avoid this, and I need to force any user of that class to provide the configuration.

Comment: So why not de-convert your classes in the new project from NIBs to code?

Comment: It's not a pet project. I can't do it, the product managers won't allocate any time for me to do that. And I think bringing that idea to fellow developers would cause good laughs. No pun intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not build on top of the standard `UIViewController` initializer for NIBs then?

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle parameter1:(id)param1...
    NSAssert(param1 != nil && param2 != nil ...);
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle]) {
        //Custom initializations here.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: How is this forcing to provide all the configuration parameters at initialisation? There is no point in having internal default parameters, I 'd like to enforce that any developer that will reuse the control, will see what is there to be configured. 
The control, doesn't have public properties at all.

Comment: What are you talking about?  By making this the only initializer that works, you can, in effect, enforce this as the default initializer (besides, it should be clearly marked in any framework header what the default initializer is).  And if you don't want public properties, here's your chance.  Declare some private properties in a class extension and set their values to the given parameters.  If you really want to enforce this as the default, return nil from the other initializers.

Comment: What is not understandable in a fact, that I want to force the developer to provide all! configuration data during initialisation of that custom control and I want ensure that unless he provides it, there is no custom control and that the developer doesn't have to study all possible properties of that control, but instead I want to give him comfortable experience, hence the custom initialiser? 
And the other requirement is that this custom control is added into any other project as a UIView in IB with Custom class option changed to UICustomClass in Identity inspector?`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the nature of the pseudo-code in my answer.  I didn't want to write an initializer that takes 10 properties out, so I added ellipses (...) to show that ***you need to write the rest yourself*** the code is correct, you just are reading it wrong.

Comment: @EarlGray if you want to force them to put in all the parameters, see the revised code above.  It will crash if one of the parameters is nil.

Comment: Oh man, you are right. I did not see the whole code because I am blind (and had a stressful day that day)and missed the "parameter part" on the right. This window for code is a bit too narrow :)
I only saw an overriden initwithnibname...not a custom method.
Off course, I can do it as you suggest. Accepted as the answer.